# Matching part of the string using or operator

Tags: javascript, regex

The URL string may look like:

```
http://test.com/index.php?page=xxx&item=51
```

or

```
http://test.com/index.php?page=xxx&object=22&bla=14
```

or

```
http://test.com/index.php?page=xxx
```

How I would be able to capture word **xxx**?

Tried something like this:

```
url_string.match(/\b\?page\=(.*)(\&|$)/)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually `*` does a greedy match, you need to add a reluctant quantifier `?` just after to `*` to do a shortest possible match.

```
url_string.match(/\?page\=(.*?)(?:\&|$)/gm)
```

Group index 1 contains the value of `page`

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/cO4oM4/3)

Answer (score 3):

You can simplify your regex a lot like this:

```
var matches = url_string.match(/\?page=([^&\n]*)/i);
```

Comment: See updated regex. Also what you're seeing in demo can only occur in multiline text and that won't be the case with a single URL. However I did update it to take care of it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

`url_string.match(/\?page=([^&]+)/)`

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/cO4oM4/2)

Comment: You don't need `\b` either.